Why do no files rebuild when I touch drivers/net/dsa/dsa_loop_bdinfo.c
In a 6.1.55 Linux kernel build, after a full make, if I touch a file marked as "=y" in the .config (e.g. net/devres.c) I see that the compiler rebuilds the corresponding .o file, as expected.
user@machine:/opt/linux-imx$ touch net/devres.c
user@machine:/opt/linux-imx$ make
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CC      net/devres.o
  AR      net/built-in.a
...

If I do the same for drivers/net/dsa/dsa_loop_bdinfo.c nothing is rebuilt!
user@machine:/opt/linux-imx$ touch drivers/net/dsa/dsa_loop_bdinfo.c
user@machine:/opt/linux-imx$ make
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
user@machine:/opt/linux-imx$

I've checked that a module marked as "=m" in the same directory (drivers/net/dsa/dsa_loop.c) gets rebuilt as a module, as expected, if it is touched.
I've checked the contents of drivers/net/dsa/Makefile:
...
obj-$(CONFIG_NET_DSA_LOOP)      += dsa_loop.o
ifdef CONFIG_NET_DSA_LOOP
obj-$(CONFIG_FIXED_PHY)         += dsa_loop_bdinfo.o
endif
...

... and the relevant lines in the .config file:
CONFIG_NET_DSA_LOOP=m
CONFIG_FIXED_PHY=y

I have tried commenting out the ifdef and endif lines around the dsa_loop_bdinfo.o line in the Makefile, to no avail.
I have tried changing the Makefile to use the following line:
obj-y                             += dsa_loop_bdinfo.o 

Any suggestions?
Update:
The .config contains:
CONFIG_NET_DSA=m

and the Makefile in drivers/net/ contains:
obj-$(CONFIG_NET_DSA) += dsa/

so yes, @sawdust, this does appear to be an attempt to compile a "-y" file within a "-m" directory.
It looks like this was first discovered in 2019 and fixed in kernel version 5.1.5 (https://www.uwsg.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1905.2/08067.html) but subsequently lost/reverted.
Anyway, now I've got the modules building I've just got to find out how to use them... my naive insmodding isn't getting me the results I hoped for!

Your configuration specifies a split: one object is built for obj-m and the other is built for obj-y. The twain shall not be combined. Since you intend a loadable kernel module rather than a built-in, try reconfiguring CONFIG_FIXED_PHY to also be a module.

@sawdust Thanks for spotting that. I will give it a go. However, isn't that the sort of thing that make menuconfig should guard against?

Linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78147648/how-do-i-know-when-the-dsa-loop-and-dsa-loop-bdinfo-linux-kernel-modules-are-wor
